# Trouble Sending Elementor Form Data via cURL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, elementor

I'm adapting the code to retrieve information from the Elementor form. I've referred to the [documentation](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/forms/), and I have an example code snippet.

```
function send_custom_webhook( $record, $handler ) {

    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

    // Replace MY_FORM_NAME with the name you gave your form
    if ( 'MY_FORM_NAME' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }

    wp_remote_post(
        'https://api.example.com/',
        [
            'body' => $fields,
        ]
    );
}
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', 'send_custom_webhook', 10, 2 );
```

And here is the code from the platform that I'm attempting "Wolkvox", I've referred to the [documentation](https://www.wolkvox.com/en/apis-v2-2/2-1-inserting-records-in-the-campaign-predictive/), and I have an example code snippet.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'[{
            "customer_name": "name",
            "customer_id": "customerID",
            "opt1": "tel1",
           

}]',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'wolkvox-token: '
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


}
```

The following is the output when I integrate both code samples

```
function send_to_external_api( $record, $handler ) {
   
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'Testing' );

  
    if ( 'Testing' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }


    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }

   
    $data = json_encode([
        "customer_name" => $fields['name'], 
        "customer_id" => $fields['customerID'], 
        "tel1" => $fields['tel1'], 
    ]);

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => '',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'wolkvox-token: ',
            'Content-Type: application/json', 
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response; 
}
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', 'send_to_external_api', 10, 2 );
```

However, it's not sending any information to the API. Upon checking the Wolkvox platform, there doesn't appear to be any added information.

I have replaced the corresponding information in both the `CURLOPT_URL` and the token.

I would appreciate any guidance regarding what I might be doing wrong or why the information isn't being sent.

Comment: So what was the actual response you got from the API?

Comment: @CBroe  With the current code, I didn't receive any response. Honestly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: First of all, use `var_dump` instead of echo, to make such debug outputs. echo will show you _nothing_, if the value is false. Second, such debug outputs inside of hook callback functions might not always end up in a "visible" place, so put an `exit;` after your debug output to have all processing end there, and check what you get then.

Comment: @CBroe I've added the following code snippet:
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($response === false) {
    $error_message = curl_error($curl);
    var_dump($error_message);
    exit;
}
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
Where can I view the error message?

Comment: _"Where can I view the error message?"_ - you just dumped it into the output stream - so either directly on the _page_ this request results in, or if this is a background request, in the response you can inspect via your browser dev tools.

Comment: @CBroe Nothing is being displayed, and it's possible that the function isn't even being called, which is why it's not causing any errors. In the end, I added it like this: curl_close($curl); var_dump($response); exit;

Comment: Is the form getting submitted directly (loads a new page=, or is it submitted via AJAX in the background? In the latter case, you should inspect the request in your browser dev tools network panel, to see any potential debug output in the response.